# Auto type deduction and passing a lambda to an std::function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Lets assume that I have a function with the following signature:

```
void foo(std::function<void(int&)>& bar);
```

The following call compiles successfully:

```
foo([](int& x) { ++x; });
```

This compiles successfully too:

```
std::function<void(int&)> myFunction = [](int& x) { ++x; };
foo(myFunction);
```

But with auto type deduction it suddenly fails to compile:

```
auto myFunction = [](int& x) { ++x; };
foo(myFunction);
```

AFAIK the deduced type of lambda is unspecified, but it is supposed to act as a functor/callable. What I do not understand is that how is it possible to assign the same lambda to an `std::function<void(int&)>` if it is not allowed to be passed as a function parameter for the same type?

Tested on GCC v4.8.5, with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: With missing `const` all compile fine ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b41be352aa94d8d)). but without only second snippet works (as I expect) [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59697370e031fa8e)

Comment: Your first example compiles???  It does not [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/183f6b859831fa01) or [here](https://godbolt.org/g/JmruPu)

Comment: Yeah, after the other answers mentioned that that code should not compile I checked on both cpp.sh and godbolt (using gcc v4.8.5 there) and it indeed does not compile. Weird, because on my work machine gcc has no problem compiling it, and now I get answers explaining how you can only bind rvalues to constant references...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given this case;

```
std::function<void(int&)> myFunction = [](int& x) { ++x; };
foo(myFunction);
```

The conversion happens and the result is stored in the named object `myFunction`. In turn, the named object can bind to the reference required for `foo`.

Given the other two cases;

```
foo([](int& x) { ++x; });
// and
auto myFunction = [](int& x) { ++x; };
foo(myFunction);
```

The conversion from the named object `myFunction` (in the second case) to the `std::function` could take place (in both cases); but a temporary is produced. The temporary cannot bind to the `std::function` reference required for `foo`, hence the error. Adding a `const` as follows allows the code to compile;

```
void foo(std::function<void(int&)> const& bar);
```

Temporaries are allowed to bind to `const` references.

[Sample code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9301bfab0a143132).

Answer (score 2):

> The following call compiles successfully:
>
> ```
> foo([](int& x) { ++x; });
> ```

Wrong, it [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/g/OzGuzP). The reason is that you cannot bind a temporary to the reference.

For the same reason:

```
auto myFunction = [](int& x) { ++x; };
foo(myFunction);
```

does not compile too. The type of `myFunction` is a type of lambda, so temporary is created passing it to the `foo` because `foo` expects `std::function<void(int&)>&` and `myFunction` has to be implicitly converted to the `std::function<void(int&)>`.

Here:

```
std::function<void(int&)> myFunction = [](int& x) { ++x; };
foo(myFunction);
```

no temporary is created. So the code compiles successfully.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is not the same as a value.

```
std::function<void(int&)>&
```

This is a reference.

```
std::function<void(int&)>
```

This is a value.

```
int&
```

This is a reference.

```
int
```

This is a value.

```
int x = 3.0;
```

The above works.

```
int& x = 3.0;
```

The above doesn't work.

```
std::function<void(int&)> f = [](int&x){++x;};
```

The above works.

```
std::function<void(int&)>& f = [](int&x){++x;};
```

The above doesn't work.

```
void foo(std::function<void(int&)>& bar);
```

`foo` takes a reference to a `std::function`.  Which means it needs to be passed an actual `std::function`, not something convertible to it.

```
void foo2(std::function<void(int&)> const& bar);
```

`foo2` takes a `const&` to a `std::function`.  Here, you are allowed to pass something convertible-to a `std::function`.

```
void foo3(std::function<void(int&)> bar);
```

`foo3` takes a `std::function` by value.  Here you are allowed to pass something convertible to a `std::function`.

A lambda is not a `std::function`, but it is convertible to one so long as the signatures are compatible.  So this behaves like the "passing a `double` to an `int`" case, where the `double` converts-to an `int`, but you cannot get an `int&` to a `double`.

C++ permits `const&` to temporaries, but not `&`, because `&` implies you intend to change it, and the changes won't propagate through the temporary.